# Wix Installer Error 2343

Tags: xml, user-interface, wix, windows-installer

so I have been trying to develop this installer for my application. I decided to change my GUI to `<UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />`. According to a tutorial that I was reading I also need to include `<Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="TOP_LEVEL_DIR" />` if I use that GUI. But, since I changed the GUI and added this line I am getting an error (2343). I have posted the MSI Log below as well and it is complaining about a location?

**Error:**
    MSI (c) (CC:84) [13:27:33:140]: Note: 1: 2343 
    DEBUG: Error 2343:  Specified path is empty.
    The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2343. The arguments are: , , 
    MSI (c) (CC:84) [13:27:34:663]: Product: Viewer 1.0 -- The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2343. The arguments are: , ,

```
Action ended 13:27:34: WelcomeDlg. Return value 3.
MSI (c) (CC:DC) [13:27:34:672]: Doing action: FatalError
Action 13:27:34: FatalError. 
Action start 13:27:34: FatalError.
Action 13:27:34: FatalError. Dialog created
Action ended 13:27:36: FatalError. Return value 2.
Action ended 13:27:36: INSTALL. Return value 3.
```

**Code:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows-1252'?>
<Wix xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi'>
  <Product Name='Viewer 1.0' Id='*' UpgradeCode='PUT-GUID-HERE'
    Language='1033' Codepage='1252' Version='1.0.0' Manufacturer='Direct'>
    <Package Id='*' Keywords='Installer' Description="Viewer Installer"
      Comments='Installer is a registered trademark.' Manufacturer='Direct'
      InstallerVersion='100' Languages='1033' Compressed='yes' 
      SummaryCodepage='1252' />

    <Media Id='1' Cabinet='Sample.cab' EmbedCab='yes' DiskPrompt="CD-ROM #1" />
    <Property Id='DiskPrompt' Value="1.0 Installation [1]" />
    <Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="TOP_LEVEL_DIR" />

    <Directory Id='TARGETDIR' Name='SourceDir'>
      <Directory Id='ProgramFilesFolder' Name='PFiles'>
        <Directory Id='Direct' Name='DMD'>
          <Directory Id='INSTALLDIR' Name='Viewer'>

            <Component Id='MainExecutable' Guid='*'>
              <Shortcut Id="startmenuViewer" Directory="ProgramMenuDir" 
                        Name="Viewer" WorkingDirectory='INSTALLDIR' 
                        Icon="Viewer.exe" IconIndex="0" Advertise="yes" />
              <Shortcut Id="desktopViewer" Directory="DesktopFolder" 
                        Name="Viewer" WorkingDirectory='INSTALLDIR' 
                        Icon="Viewer.exe" IconIndex="0" Advertise="yes" />

              <File Id='EXE' Name='Viewer.exe' DiskId='1' 
                    Source='Viewer.exe' KeyPath='yes'>
              </File>
                <ProgId Id="DMDCCDAV" Description="Viewer">
                   <Extension Id="xml" >
                    <Verb Id="open" Argument="&quot;%1&quot;" 
                          TargetFile="EXE" />
                   </Extension>
                </ProgId>
            </Component>

          </Directory>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>

      <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder" Name="Programs">
        <Directory Id="ProgramMenuDir" Name="Viewer">
          <Component Id="ProgramMenuDir" Guid="*">
            <RemoveFolder Id='ProgramMenuDir' On='uninstall' />
            <RegistryValue Root='HKCU' 
                           Key='Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]' 
                           Type='string' Value='' KeyPath='yes' />
          </Component>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>

      <Directory Id="DesktopFolder" Name="Desktop" />
    </Directory>

    <Feature Id='Complete' Title='Viewer Installation' 
             Display='expand' Level='1' ConfigurableDirectory='INSTALLDIR'>
    <Feature Id='MainProgram' Title='Viewer Program' 
             Description='The main executable.' Level='1'>
      <ComponentRef Id='MainExecutable' />
      <ComponentRef Id='ProgramMenuDir' />
    </Feature>
    </Feature>

    <UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_ErrorProgressText" />

    <Icon Id="Viewer.exe" SourceFile="Viewer.exe" />

  </Product>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The value of `<Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="TOP_LEVEL_DIR" />` is what you specify as allowing the user to set with the UI dialog box. In this case, you are identifying `TOP_LEVEL_DIR` as the ID of the directory that you want the user to set, but you don't have it mapped to any corresponding `Directory` tag.

Assuming you're trying to allow them to change the root install directory, try setting the value of `WIXUI_INSTALLDIR` from `TOP_LEVEL_DIR` to `INSTALLDIR` instead.

See [this reference](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/dialog_reference/wixui_installdir.html) for more info.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. That did fix my problem. Thank you. Now I'm off to attempt default file associations and .net framework bundles :/